# Mailbox Pattern with Variable Arguments in C++

Tags: design-patterns, c++

In a game I'm developing, the GUI thread is catching user actions, and the simulation thread is responsible of handling and responding to them.

To minimize complexity and delay, I predefined all possible action types the user may trigger, and created an array of "opcodes". The GUI thread sets "happened" to the relevant `array[opcode]` in real time, and the simulation thread, in the proper position in code, samples `array[opcode]` and acts on `array[opcode].data` if `array[opcode].happened == true`.

The problem is that each opcode has a different set (size, types) of arguments. Currently I'm only allowing string arguments, and parses them in the simulation thread - not very efficient. Another solution I can think of is polymorphic opcode class and dynamically casting it in the simulation thread - ugly.

I named this the "mailbox pattern", but I'm sure someone more clever has solved (and named) it already. A pointer to a more elegant solution would be great.

Comment: Since you have a finite set of opcodes, a tagged union is the most straightforward solution. Is there a reason you're not using that approach?

Comment: @Doval I didn't think of that solution. It would be kind of wasteful in case a single opcode's data is much larger than the others, no?

Comment: Have you looked at other implementations such as Qt's [signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)? Maybe you can use that or mirror its design on something simpler.

Comment: @liorda Well, is it? I assumed this was mostly keyboard/mouse/joystick/screen data, so there'd be relatively little variation - generally 1-3 integer fields. I can't imagine speed or space being an issue here, relative to the amount of processing done in the game thread. You might also consider having a real mailbox, i.e. a queue. What happens if the simulation thread starts to choke? As it stands right now, you'll lose all but the most recent action for a given opcode.

Comment: @Snowman It seems like the callbacks (slots) are invoked by the signaling thread, and if so, I can't use that since the simulation handling code may get messy.

Comment: @Doval User actions are mostly button clicks, where I need to store the relevant GUI state as data. GUI update frequency is pretty slow compared to the simulation thread update rate, so choking is not a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `happened` idiom; if for some reason your processing thread gets delayed, `happened` may still be true from the last user action. In any case you definitely need a mutex to ensure that `data` is not updated while you're reading it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't use a number of individual event queues, one for each type of action? You could use condition variables to inform the sim thread about a new event, and dispatch a callback for the respective event in that thread.

Comment: @liorda Qt's signal-slot mechanism by default runs on the thread associated with the reciever, posted to that thread's event loop iff the sender is associated with a different thread. see [Qt::ConnectionType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array, you could use a `vector<EventClass>` (where `EventClass` is whatever type your current array is). Then you could just iterate through the vector and process each event until it's empty, assuming the GUI thread won't be adding events while the simulation thread is processing them (this could be achieved with mutexes of some kind)... You'd then only have to process active events, since the vector would only contain events that have happened. It could work like so:

```
class EventClass {
    EventClass(int _o, string _d) : opcode(_o), data(_d) {}
    int opcode;
    string data;
}
//somewhere available to both threads, declare the vector:
vector<EventClass> ActiveEvents;

void GUI_Process_Events(){
    //...
    ActiveEvents.push_back(The_Event_That_Just_Happened);
}

void Simulation_Process_Events(){
    //this will iterate through all the active events and
    //act on each of them
    for(int i = 0; i < ActiveEvents.size(); i++){
        //this gets the item at the back of the vector
        EventClass Current_Event = ActiveEvents.back();

        //assuming Process(EventClass e) will process the event
        Process(Current_Event);

        //this will then remove the event from the vector
        ActiveEvents.pop_back();
    }
}
```

If necessary, you could use a vector of pointers to EventClass objects (but then of course you must destroy them as well):

```
class EventClass {
    EventClass(int _o, string _d) : opcode(_o), data(_d) {}
    int opcode;
    string data;
}
//somewhere available to both threads, declare the vector:
vector<EventClass*> ActiveEvents;

void GUI_Process_Events(){
    //...
    ActiveEvents.push_back(PointerTo_The_Event_That_Just_Happened);
}

void Simulation_Process_Events(){
    //this will iterate through all the active events and
    //act on each of them
    for(int i = 0; i < ActiveEvents.size(); i++){
        //this gets the item at the back of the vector
        EventClass* Current_Event = ActiveEvents.back();

        //assuming Process(EventClass e) will process the event
        Process(Current_Event);

        //delete the object pointed to by the element in the vector
        delete Current_Event;

        //this will then remove the event from the vector
        ActiveEvents.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. However, currently I'm handling each user action in a different place in the code, and my code has a lot of `if (*.happened())` scattered around. Maybe that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to make

```
struct Data
{
   //enter the common data here
};

struct OpcodeData: public Data
{
   //enter opcode specific data here
};
```

and then your `array[opcode].data` would be a pointer of of type `Data *` actually assigned to an instance of `OpcodeData *`.

But then again - do you really need to have the data in an array?
Why not have just variables opcode1Data, opcode2Data etc.?

Or even better: could the data be grouped by their meaning (physicsData, movementData, etc.) instead of by the opcode?

Answer (score 0):

> I predefined all possible action types the user may trigger, and created an array of "opcodes".

Use a `struct` or `class` instead of an array. Then you can store different types for each GUI action.

If you want to preserve index-based lookup, you can use a 
`std::tuple` instead.

Remember that an array stores a homogeneous collection of fixed size (i.e. known at compile time), whereas a struct stores a heterogeneous collection of fixed size.